# Rails jquery datepicker saving to database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I am using the jquery datepicker for a datetime field for a user on a form. Here is what I have so far:

views/users/_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.text_field :date_joined, class: 'form-control border-input datepicker' %>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden-date-joined">
```

custom.js

```
$(function() {
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
  altField: '#hidden-date-joined',
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
 });
});
```

When I select a date, such as "October 4 2016" it shows in the input field as "10/04/16" but it is submitting to the database as "2016-04-10" so it shows April 10. I have been trying for hours to figure this out but I just can't seem to find the correct solution.

Comment: what datatype are you storing it as to the database? A string?

Comment: I'm storing it as `datetime`

Comment: Your altFormat is mm-dd and the other only has m/d maybe that is causing it.

Comment: I know. I want it to save to the database as yy-mm-dd. In this example it should be "2016-10-04" instead of "2016-04-10".

Comment: Make sure to install the https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date gem.